# Backgroundsetup not in the background?

Tags: backgrounds

I have a backgroundsetup for every page in my latex file. But I want the content of the backgroundsetup in front of the rest of the document. Is this possible with backgroundsetup or do I need to use another package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{background}
\usepackage{tikz}


\backgroundsetup{
    scale=1,
    color=black,
    opacity=1,
    angle=0,
    position=current page.center,
    vshift=0cm,
    contents={
        Some text that should be over the rectangle
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=blue] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: I added a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: See `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\put(x,y){...}}` (standard LaTeX).  The x,y coordinates are relative to the top left corner of the page (use negative values for y).  See also the tikzpagenodes package.